# Union lines in xml data with bash

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, sed

Im trying to post xml to api with bash. Some xml data couldnt return correct answer cause stcructure of this files is incorrect.
and reason of this whitespaces between special string, if line has longer than 80 columns then line continue from new line, and left "non closed" xml tags.
help to solve this case.

i need to join lines on "onedictvalue>" (13 line) tag or delete space between "]" symbols (15 line).

May be there setting code which not limited column size to 80?

xml body.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <document>
   <function name="catalogAddRecord">
     <param name="ittinbalasy">545</param>
     <param name="atananalet">45464</param>
     <param name="albasty">29417</param>
     <param name="zheksuryn">4</param>
     <param name="onbagan">999</param>=
     <param name="dictrecords">
       <onedictvalue>
         <fieldid>12439</fieldid>
         <values>
           <value><![CDATA[Блаала/Есин барда елинди тап/Кырсык келсе су куриды
 нционного ввывыв/Департа/Управление вывывввввввввыыыыыыыввввввввввввввввввыв и
  работы с кукуку йцйцыфыфыф/Отывававвававаывыыыыыыыыыыыыыыыыыыывывы/Группа №4]
 ]></value>
         </values>
       </onedictvalue>
     </param>
   </function>
   <client name="InternalSite" version="0.01"/>
 </document>
```

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: i cant install this tool to our linux machine, dont have needed roots. others dont do it in near time.

Comment: `xmlstarlet` or any xmlparser will fail on this as the `CDATA` tag is wrongly closed due to the linebreak.

Comment: @RKURBAN - By "prettifying" the XML body, you removed the very point of the question, hence rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would suggest to make use of an XML-parser such as xmlstarlet or anything of that order. But since you work with broken XML files, the `CDATA` is not cleanly closed due to a nasty newline, I might suggest something like this:

```
$ cat file.xml | tr '\n' '\0' | sed 's/]\r\?\x0\]>/]]>/g' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

This task decided by set code when initialize conect to oracle to take xml data from lob column.
Default connection took 80 characters per line, now 700.
Thank you to attention to all.

```
data="$(
$DBCLPATH/sqlplus -s $DBUSER@$DBNAME/****<<EOF
set head off
**SET LINESIZE 700**
select to_char(d."depts".getCLOBVal())||';' AS xml_val FROM dwh_stage.motiw_insert_rows d WHERE rownum < 20;
EOF
)"
```